# Angular Service not getting hit, function is undefined TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an extension method. Inside that extension method I tried to call the web API using the httpClient, however the method which is calling the HTTP is giving me an undefined error.

When using a debugger, I can see that my debugger is not going inside the class and I can't figure out why.

**Note: This is an Extension method, not a service class**

*Extension.model.ts*

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    JsonServiceReceiver(): any[];
  }
}

class serviceChecker {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  asd() {
    this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'JsonServiceReceiver', {

  value: function() {

    // according to my knowledge I am getting an error here, while object creation.

    let objservice: serviceChecker;
    objservice.asd();
  },
  enumerable: false
});

export {}
```

> Error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'asd' of undefined

Here is the file from which I am attempting to call the extension method:

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './Employee.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  EmployeArray: Employee[] = [];

  submit() {
    this.EmployeArray = Object.JsonServiceReceiver();
    console.log("data", this.EmployeArray);
  }

}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Again, I'm not using services, I'm using an extension method in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Well this construction: `let objservice : serviceChecker;` is not really creating the object, but rather assigning the type to the variable. So your variable **objservice** just has the type of your service. To actually create it, you need to use the `let objservice = new serviceChecker()`

Comment: tried got an error 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I actually try to help you with this

Comment: The service can't just be created since it has a dependency. Ideally you should let angular create the service and inject it into your `AppComponent` then pass it into your extension method. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: ya I know that by creating another file of service and then access the service using my extension, but I want to perform it in same file service + extension

Comment: I'd say using http-calls inside an extension method sounds like bad practice. Do you have to make this an extension method? IMO extension methods should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: Where the code lives is of no importance, if the extension is expected to call a method on the service then it must have a reference to an instance of that service, not just knowledge of the type. You're gonna have to use DI at some point in order to get `HttpClient`, and an extension method can't access Angular's DI system. I agree with @ShamPooSham that this isn't a good place for an extension method.

Comment: IMO extension methods...?? well I am just trying to do some combination to work out, Can you provide me with some reasons on which basis you are avoiding me to use it

Comment: IMO = In my opinion

Comment: Extension methods are best used for simple tasks (preferably pure functions) with no dependencies other than the data itself. Why do you want to use extensions methods in this case? It seems like you could just accept the service into your `AppComponent` via DI and just call it.

Comment: @UncleDave can you provide mi with code , along with it some powerfull reasons to not use extension method

Comment: I think the fact you're struggling with the above code is reason enough. It seems like a very simple task for a regular service. Why don't you try writing it without using an extension method and using Angular's DI system and see how easy it is by comparison.

Comment: As much as I  wanted to help, guys are write, I can't see a purpose for extension methods to have this kind of functionality. As they would be visible for all objects and that's not right performance wise.

Comment: @UncleDave I am trying to perform a heavy task on an extension method, will it give me performance problem or memory problem

Comment: 1) It complicates things 2) Eventually you will bloat the javascript object prototype, making it hard for tools like webpack to optimize (through treeshaking for example)

Comment: @UncleDave well i have wrote lots of services in angular but i was just trying allot of different way with different combination

Comment: Performing a "heavy task" in an extension method won't be any better or worse than performing it anywhere else, from a performance/memory point of view. The issue here is code complexity; where the extension method makes the code more complex for no payoff.

Comment: @UncleDave just correct me if I am wrong, extension method, if I create a bunch of extension methods for my project which consists of both heavy, normal, small task then will it give me performance issue . I am thinking of using the extension method on a wide scale just my thinking! need your opinion